IF $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent, when are $X$ and $Y$ independent
Let $X^2$ and $Y^2$ be continuous independent random variables with support the real numbers. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent with support the real numbers, or do I need additional conditions? An example is where  $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are two independent $\chi^2(1)$ random variables.
I must show
$$\mbox{Prob}(X \le x ,Y \le y) = \mbox{Prob}(X \le x) \mbox{Prob}(Y \le y) \quad  \mbox{for any $x$, $y$ real}.$$
I know
$$\mbox{Prob}(X^2\le x,Y^2 \le y) = \mbox{Prob}(X^2 \le x) \mbox{Prob}(Y^2 \le y) \quad  \mbox{for any $x$, $y$ real},$$
so,
$$\mbox{Prob}(-\sqrt{x} \le  X \le \sqrt{x} ,-\sqrt{y} \le  Y \le  \sqrt{y})= \mbox{Prob}(-\sqrt{x} \le X \le \sqrt{x}) \mbox{Prob} (-\sqrt{y} \le Y \le  \sqrt{y}) \quad  \mbox{for any $x$, $y$ non-negative real}.$$
I am unsure how to progress from here. Should I perhaps require symmetric random variables with expectation 0?

X² and Y² independent is certainly not sufficient that X and Y are independent. Just imagine independent variables Z and Y and define $X = |Z| \times sign(Y)$. I believe that this has been discussed on the website before.

The supports of $X^2$ and $Y^2$ cannot include any negative numbers.  Perhaps you meant to assume that the supports of $X$ and $Y$ are the reals? // If $(X^2,Y^2)$ and $(X,Y)$ are independent, then so is the joint Bernoulli variable $(I,J)$ with $I=(X+|X|)^2/(4X^2)$ and $J=(Y+|Y|)^2/(4Y^2).$ The converse of this is proven in my answer in the duplicate.

You will need extra conditions, I will show with an example. First, let $X, Y$ be independent standard normal, and independently of both let $Z$ be a Rademacher random variable (that is, possible values are $\pm 1$ with equal probability).  Now, as can be checked, $XZ$ will be independent from $YZ$. But the independence results from the symmetry of $X$ and $Y$.
So, instead take $X, Y$ as independent $\mathcal{N}(1, 1)$. Then, $XZ$ and $YZ$ will be dependent. Intuitively, this is because if $XZ$ is negative, that will increase the probability that $YZ$ is also negative.
But $(XZ)^2 = X^2$ and $(YZ)^2=Y^2$ are independent.
